# The best method to send images interactively from Haskell backend to Qt QUI

Tags: c++, performance, qt, haskell, rpc

I'm building an application consisting of two parts: QtQuick GUI (C++) and Haskell back-end processing the images using [**`repa`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) and [**`accelerate`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/accelerate) packages.

I want to interactively display images in GUI. I would love not to copy the data but use some kind of shared memory or any other mechanism, which would allow me to gain the most performance.

What is the best way to "transfer" and display these images interactively in C++ GUI?

I heard about [**`HQK`**](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/HQK) and [**`qtHaskell`**](http://qthaskell.berlios.de/), but it supports only `qtquick` up to v4.8 (and we need v5.0 - v5.2)

Comment: Does the QtQuick/C++ side call into Haskell, or does the Haskell backend run independently, with communication happening in a more IPC-like fashion? Which side "drives" production of the images? (I'm asking because I've been pondering something similar myself lately, and these questions seem important…)

Comment: It's both way communication but most images will be pushed into GUI from Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Haskell but in lablqt (my library for building QtQuick+OCaml applications, http://kakadu.github.io/lablqt/) I would try this method:

1. We store image in OCaml/Haskell side as a mutable array of chars (in OCaml it is called string) and we prevent GC from moving this value.
2. In C++ side we store address of our image and us it to build QString. I don't expect any copying because QString uses copy-on-write.
3. PROFIT

Maybe this approach sucks because if we will need resize image, GC will instantiate new image, copy old to new one and after that we will need to update pointer to image in C++ side.

Excuse me, in my idea will be unusable.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, could you use `mmap`? There is [vector-mmap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-mmap) for Haskell which maps a file into a (shared) memory read only or as mutable vector.

Comment: Looks interesting. Did you try to use it in similar cases?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just tried some small examples with it, but then did not need it. My usecase were large data structures to be mapped into a file so that the virtual memory management does the job. There are also some more low level wrappers for `mmap` which work on raw pointers, maybe there is a way to get repa to directly use them. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable on repa or accelerate can provide infos.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Now, I'm testing ZeroMQ. I read on haskell irc that it's performance is enough for that case.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at [FFI](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Using_the_FFI) as you could probably get away with embedding your haskell code directly inside of your C++ code!  This would also allow you to share memory between them.

You could also open a pipe in C++ to your haskell program and pass the data that way, though you are then making a copy in memory.  Unless your images are huge I doubt making a copy in memory would make much of a performance difference.